# What would cause an anime series to be transferred to another studio?

Tags: anime-production, log-horizon

Specifically, I noticed the transfer of studios for Log Horizon (Satelight to Studio Deen),

Surely there are more anime series that have changed studios. Why does this happen?

Comment: There was the case of Hayate no Gotoku switching from Synergy (Season 1) to J.C Staff (Season 2) since the target audience has changed. That doesn't seem to be the case of Log Horizon though, since it is continued to be aired in early evening.

Comment: Is it between seasons this switch has occurred? if so i would assume licencing agreements with Satelight was for just 1 season and with the money/popularity Studio Deen decided to licences the next season. Nomad did the first 2 Rozen Maiden Anime and the OVA while Studio Deen is doing Zurückspulen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is based off of what I know from reading "Hey Answerman" every once in a while, but I think it should be a good enough guess of the process:

1. The Production Committee for Log Horizon decided to adapt the novels into an anime.
2. They bought 25 weeks worth of a time slot because they were pretty confident that it would be more successful than a typical 13 week anime.
3. They contracted an animation studio to animate it (Satelight).
4. The anime aired and it had a good response with ratings and DVD sales. (And, more importantly, Light Novel sales.)
5. The Production Committee thought "Hey, the first series turned a profit and there is a demand for more, lets make a second series"
6. The Production Committee checks with Satelight and decides not to use them again because they were either too expensive or they had already contracted to animate another anime during the proposed season (scheduling conflicts).
7. The Production Committee finds some other animation studio (Studio Deen) that doesn't currently have plans for that season and goes with them because its better to do a second series now while the fan interest is high than to wait until Satelight is available.